# Does SQL Server connect from Azure to Visual Studio using Windows authentication?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-sql-database

I have an application developed using Visual Studio and SQL Server database. The default permission is Windows authentication on my local machine. I have also created an [Azure SQL Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIsDY.png). Now I am connecting this database with Visual Studio.

I get this error:

[image]

I tried SQL Server authentication as well but it is not accepting user name and Password which I created in SQL Server in SQL Server authentication mode:

[SQL Connection error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4jCO.png)

But the same credentials work in SQL Server:

[Same credentials work here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdqMQ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cant use windows auth (like the error suggests) to access Azure SQL, you need to use sql auth and\or Azure AD auth.

I tried SQL Authentication as well but It is not accepting UserName and Password which I created in SQL server in SQL server Authentication. - this only means you made a typo somewhere.

Comment: I have uploaded the Image. Please see this and suggest me. The same credential works in SQL Server SQL Authentication. No Ideas why I am getting this error. Please suggest.

Comment: what do you mean `works in SQL Server SQL Authentication`

Comment: When I open SQL server from my local machine and then If I put the same credentials which I had put in `User Name` and `password` fields. It works here.

Comment: what does open `sql server` mean? you cant really open sql server.

Comment: I have added another image. If you see both the image, I have supplied same credentials, still does not work.

Comment: because you connect to sql express in your latest image

Comment: can you please invite me for chat

Comment: why? just check sql server name you are using, its not azure sql, its your sql express

Comment: Appreciated, if you could guide me what should I put in UserName and password field. From where shall I get this information.

Comment: you define password when you create Azure SQL, if you dont know it you can reset it using azure portal, same way you can find username for azure sql, just navigate to the azure sql server resource